# Основные источники информации по созданию программ для критических отраслей

Tags: безопасность

Есть отрасли, где принципиально важна не производительность, удобство или поддерживаемость программ, а такое понятие как надежность (атомная отрасль, космическая, авиация, жд транспорт, гидроэлектростанции и т.д.) Например, есть требования, которые запрещают иметь бесконечные циклы в коде, иметь процедуры и функции, которые не используются (что сразу ограничивает использование универсальных операционных систем) и т.д. Подскажите наиболее авторитетные источники информации по методам разработки таких программ

Comment: пока начну наиболее интересные ссылки добавлять: https://habr.com/en/post/308634/

Comment: https://www.itu.int/ITU-T/recommendations/rec.aspx?rec=13391

Comment: стандарты серии 61508 (ISO и гармонизованный с ними отечественный ГОСТ)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UkAa2zjA-bA&list=PLoKr-_Vv5yq4f8b2WLztojmvV2PQjMGoc&index=3

Comment: https://stepik.org/course/14905

Comment: Книги: 1) Бейбер "Программное обеспечение без ошибок: приемы и секреты создания правильных программ", 2) Грис "Наука программирования", 3) Дейкстра "Дисциплина программирования"

Comment: https://ics-cert.us-cert.gov/sites/default/files/recommended_practices/NCCIC_ICS-CERT_Defense_in_Depth_2016_S508C.pdf

Comment: ПРИКАЗ ФСТЭК от 14 марта 2014 г. No 31